# vuex module can not add element to a root state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I want to push an element to a state in my root from a module in vuex.
But I get an error: rootState.artists.push is not a funcion.

```
//in root state store.js
state:{
artists:[]
},
modules:{
artists,
}
```

```
//in module artists.js
return firestore().collection('artists').limit(15).get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        let artists = [];
                        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            artists.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
                        });
                        rootState.artists.push(...artists);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
```

I expect the array of artists in the root state should be populated but,I get rootState.artists.push is not a function.

Comment: a module gets injected into the rootstate like: `rootState[moduleName]` - i guess your module replaces your `artists` state

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your mutations synchronous and also not mutate your state in actions. Consider refactoring your code.

Another issue is that your module state does indeed replace your rootState `artists`.

Example:

```
// in store.js
state:{
  artists:[]
},

mutations: {
  updateArtists(state, artists) {
    state.artists.push(...artists);
  },
},

modules:{
  artistsModule,
}
```

---

```
// in artistsModule.js
actions: {
  updateArtists(context) {
    firestore().collection('artists').limit(15).get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let artists = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          artists.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        });
        context.commit('updateArtists', artists, { root: true });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```